# how to separate the figures of specific number using matlab?

Tags: matlab

How do I separate the figures of specific number then make a new vecto?. This vector will include the figures that have been separated separately.
For example : if i have a number as `123456789` , what is the function or command that will separate these figures of the number so that they look like this form `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`   Meaning that will turn into a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dec2base`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/dec2base.html) to obtain the figures as a char vector (i.e. string), and then convert those chars into numbers with the usual trick of subtracting `'0'`:

```
>> number = 123456789;
>> figures = dec2base(number,10)-'0'
figures =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

Comment: I am unable to thank you 'Luis' , your code is very excellent